# Django foreign key column replace

Tags: django

I have class A in database for example:

```
ID COL1 COL2 COL3
1  a    b    c
```

And column B in database:

```
ID COL1 COL2 FK_COL
1  d    e    1
2  dd   ee   1
3  ddd  eee  1
```

class B have foreign key to class A. How can I create a query to get all objects from table B where foreign key is 1 but instead of ID from A to be COL1 from A.

```
ID COL1 COL2 FK_COL
1  d    e    a
2  dd   ee   a
3  ddd  eee  a
```

Comment: you want to know how to do it in django orm or in sql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use `ForeignKey.to_field`. From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> ForeignKey.to_field
>
> The field on the related object that the relation is to. By default, Django uses the primary key of the related object.

**EDIT**: For the additional question in the comment, you'd do something like:

```
b_obj = B.objects.filter(a=1).values('colX')
```

Or, if you're coming from the A object:

```
a_obj = A.objects.get(pk=1)
b_objs = a_obj.b_subset.values('colX')
```

`colX` is the column you want displayed, and `b_subset` will depend on the name of the related model. If you do `dir(a_obj)` it will be obvious which one is it, but it should be the name of the model plus "_set".

**SECOND EDIT**: `values` can also follow relations, so to answer what is ultimately your question, you would do something like:

```
b_objs = B.objects.filter(a=1).values('COl1', 'COL2', 'FK_COL__COL1')
```

This gets you the value of the COL1 from the A table (note the double underscore to follow the relation).

Comment: see now :). I will try that in a moment.

Comment: ok, that works, but I realized now that is not what i want. let's say i have id from table A is 1. I want all rows from table B where fk id is 1 BUT in a result i want some other column to be displayed insted of fk ID

Comment: @milandjukic88, Ok, I added an answer for that, but you should update the question to clarify.

Comment: I cannot make this work :). Can you write me example outputs?

Comment: The output of what I suggested is a list of dictionaries representing the objects, it's not going to help you. It's probably easier if you experiment a bit with the model objects in the Python shell.

Comment: the part values('colX') confusing me. Is this filtering data for only one column?

Comment: Yes, that's the name of one of the model's fields. You can have more, or use just `values()` for all.

Comment: Now i dont know did you understood me :). I updated my question. I want output like third table.

Comment: with your solution I get only one column, but i want to replace one column in B and display all columns in B with that column replaced

Comment: Ah, I see. You can follow relations with `values()`, as in my updated answer.